# jQuery.ajax POST request converted to GET

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, get

I have the following jQuery code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: Url,
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //callback function here
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //report error
        }
    });
```

However, when i view this AJAX request in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), my request has been converted from a `POST` to a `GET`.

This is not allowed with the API I'm connecting to, as it must be a `POST` request.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If the API you're connecting to requires `POST`, then it isn't using `JSON-P`. If it's using `JSON-P`, then it doesn't require `POST`. (Perhaps you're confusing `JSON`, a format for data exchange, and `JSON-P`, a mechanism for getting around the Same Origin Policy?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JSONP requests can only be GETs.

Remove `dataType: 'JSONP'`.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! Will accept when I can. How can I do XSS without `JSONP`? :/

Comment: @Curt: You can use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) with [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors), provided the server you're connecting to allows you to. IE8 and 9's support for CORS is present, but broken, requiring workarounds (ones that jQuery doesn't do for you). IE10 will support it properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataType: 'JSONP',
```

is always a **GET** request

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use POST with JSONP see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-dev/5-tKI-7zQvs for more detail on this.